# Update specific column using update_all while doing joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an association something like below

User has_many roles
User has_one permission

Table names
users, roles and permissions and they are under the same schema and database

I want to fetch the roles which are admin,super_admin,sub_admin. And want to update a column in the permission table

```
 User.joins(:roles,:permission).where('roles.name in (?)', ['admin', 'sub_admin', 'super_admin']).select("permissions.*").update_all('permission.can_view_details', true)
```

Firing the above query is giving me error.

Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "can_view_details" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "schema"."users" SET "can_view_details" =...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the permissions right from the model, but using joins with User:

```
Permission.
  joins(user: :roles).
  where('users.roles IN (?)', %w[admin sub_admin super_admin]).
  update_all(can_view_details: true)
```

Comment: Perfect. it worked I just have one more question. I tried this way 
 User.joins(:roles,:permission).where('roles.name in (?)', ['admin', 'sub_admin', 'super_admin']).update(can_view_details: true). It worked as well but it took a lot of time

Comment: Hey, you can see in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update), it states that _updating a large number of records will run an UPDATE query for each record, which may cause a performance issue_.